# Java 8 : parallelstream inside forkjoinpool uses more threads when size of forkjoinpool is more than number of available processors

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

I have total 8 available processors in my system. 
when forkjoinpool is explicitly set to 8 or any number under it , parallelstream uses that number of worker threads.

But, when i use number bigger than 8 , parallelstream creates worker thread ranging from 0-15.

Is it the expected behaviour when you control number of parallel threads created by parallelstream using below code.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // 1000 names in it

ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(8);
            forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
             list.parallelStream().forEach(name -> {
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
              })
           ).get();
```